# Laravel Eloquent : belongsTo relationship - Error: Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: php, laravel

First time to try laravel eloquent relatioinstip

I know it's really simple but I am getting this error don't know what's wrong with it

I have 2 tables in data base, news and news_image

**in database**

Tables:

```
news  
id | header | details 

news_image
id | image | news_id
```

And have 2 models News , newsImage

**newsImage model :**

```
 class newsImage extends Eloquant {

    protected $table = 'news_image';
    public function news()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('News');
    }    
}
```

**News model**

```
class News extends Eloquent 
{

    protected $table = 'news';

    public $timestamps = false;


    public function image()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('newsImage');
    }


}
```

The view:

```
foreach($news as $new)
<tr>
   <td> {{$new->id}} </td>
   <td> {{ $new->header}}</td>
   <td> {{ $new->details }}</td>
   </td> {{$new->news->image}}</td>
</tr>
```

when I run this it's get  error :

> Trying to get property of non-object (View: /var/www/html/clinics/app/views/news/index.blade.php)

Any ideas on what could be causing this error?

Comment: Can you also post your News model?

Comment: updated and posted the News model

Comment: Assuming this is copy/pasted code, there is no such thing as `Eloquant` which your `newsImage` class is extending. But I'm assuming since you're not getting an error from that, this isn't copy/pasted?

Comment: getting error from what  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple things I would change:

1. In your News model, change the relationship from "image" to "images" since it's a one to many relationship. It just keeps your code clean.
2. Your foreach loop in your view should loop through all the news models, but remember that each news model has multiple images, so you should have another loop inside your existing loop to display the images, i.e. `foreach ($new->images as $image)`

   ```
   @foreach ($news as $new)
       <tr>
           <td> {{$new->id}} </td>
           <td> {{ $new->header}}</td>
           <td> {{ $new->details }}</td>
           <td>
               @foreach ($new->images as $image)
                   {{ $image->image }}
               @endforeach
           </td>
       </tr>
   @endforeach
   ```

Answer (score 3):

First, assuming what you are passing to your view is an array or Collection of `News` objects, you should probably be using `$new->image` to access the `News Item` relation. By defining the function `image()` in your `News` model, you can access the relation with either the `->image` or `->image()` calls. In either case, what you need to call is probably

`$new->image->first()->image`

To break that down:

- `->image` gets the Collection of `NewsImage` relations
- `->first()` gets the first item in the Collection
- `->image` (the secone one) gets the image field from that `NewsImage`

If the Collection has more than one item, you can instead loop over it to get all of the images as shown in the other answer.

Comment: $news = News::paginate(15);

that's what iam passing to my view 

thank you for helping i got it :)