# Cannot access belongsTo relationship in Blade through `echo`, but can through `dd`

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.8

I have a very confusing situation. My code in the Blade template is like this:

```
@foreach ($upcoming as $match)
    <?php
        dd($match->team1);
        echo $match->team1->flag_image;
    ?>
// --- snip
```

(the `<?php` tag is only for debugging and isn't part of the actual code)

If I run this code, the `dd` in the first line fires and I get the dump as expected:

[image]

But when I comment it out, the next line is unable to find the `team1` object:

```
<?php
    //dd($match->team1);
    echo $match->team1->flag_image;
?>
```

This results in:

`Trying to get property 'flag_image' of non-object`

From what I can tell, the relationships are defined properly. If they were not, the first `dd` won't have worked.

I'm really speechless that the simple `echo` is unable to load the relationship. Anyone come across something similar?

Comment: can you do a `print_r($match->team1); print_r($match->team1['flag_image'])`, it could be that team1 is empty

Comment: @AdityaThakur please don't shoot in the dark. The `dd` output shows that `$match->team1` is a valid object.

Comment: could be an array @dotslash

Comment: Check your database. It is possible that (at least) one of your record has a foreign key that the corresponding record does not exits.

Comment: "Not Shooting in Dark" but its probably an array,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel Eloquent : belongsTo relationship - Error: Trying to get property of non-object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30943344/laravel-eloquent-belongsto-relationship-error-trying-to-get-property-of-non)

Comment: @RouhollahMazarei Thanks! a lot man. I was facing the similar issue, wasted hours figuring out what the problem was. You just save me from a headache.

Answer (score 0):

You might not have a relation team1 for your $match. Hence the relationship data i.e. flag_image doesn't exits.

1. First, check your database and ensure that you have all related data..
2. Second, this kind of case is normal i.e. relation data not found and hence blade returns an error (Trying to get property 'flag_image' of non-object).

You can check if relationship exits and then try to access the property.
In you case:

```
if($match->team1)
{
  echo ($match->team1->flag_image);
}
```

OR in blade

```
 {{$match->team1?$match->team1->flag_image:'N/A'}}
```

Answer (score 0):

So, I finally managed to trace it down. I'm posting here so that it may help someone else, although this is just a case of debugging.

In my case, the collection of matches (called `upcoming`) didn't all have proper teams assigned to them. For instance, for semi-finals and finals, the teams were yet to be announced (though the venue was already announced) so the `team1_id` and `team2_id` were null in my cases.

The error was hard to spot because doing a `dd` would only inspect the first match, for which team ids were non-null. It was only when the processing loop hit the final matches that the teams were blank and the relationships started throwing errors.